# Ultimate Magus and Practiced Spellcaster

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, prestige-class, caster-level

A [Q/A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105746/9552) proposes Practiced Spellcaster to keep increasing the more valuable (Wizard) class.

The Practiced Spellcaster feat (*Complete Arcane*, p. 82) increases CL by 4, *up to the character level*.
The [Ultimate Magus](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20061010a&page=3) prestige class increases CL at levels 1, 4, 7 and 10, without any such limitation.

Can I count Practiced Spellcaster first, to reach my class level, then increase it by four, or is the feat completely wasted, is the difference between my CL and character level less than 4?