# Is the Ultimate Magus the only arcane dual-progression class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

I am looking for a class to continue the **prepared**/**spontaneous** progression that the [Ultimate Magus](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20061010a&page=3) (*Complete Mage variant*, p. 77) has.
Everything but 3rd-party publications is valid.

Is there something similar to the Ultimate Magus Prestige Class out there?

Comment: You maybe be interested in exploiting Legacy Champion or Uncanny Trickster.

Comment: What are you looking for in such class? Why Magus isn't good for you?

Comment: @Mołot “I am looking for a class to **continue** the...” Ultimate magus **is** good for them, but it’s only 10 levels long and they have more levels to take after they finish that.

Comment: What base classes are you trying to progress? It will definitely affect the answers.

Comment: @Miniman I'm assuming the most typical Sorcerer/Wizard but I don't see how it being Beguiler/Wu Jen or something weird would change anything.

Comment: @Miniman Err... pretty sure it won’t. With arcane/divine spellcasting, it would (because of Fochlucan lyrist and arcane hierophant), but not with arcane/arcane.

Comment: @KRyan Off the top of my head, Shadowcaster and Sha'ir both have special rules that would make a difference. They're almost certainly not the classes under consideration, but still, it's important to know.

Comment: @Miniman Neither of those classes is a legal choice for ultimate magus.

Comment: @KRyan Ah, I forgot that shadowcaster is only allowed into mystic theurge. And I guess I never knew that ultimate magus requires preparation specifically from a spellbook. I did say off the top of my head. Still, better to have it specified than not.

Comment: I must have misread, sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ultimate magus is indeed the only arcane/arcane dual-spellcasting-progression class.<sup>1</sup>

You could **maybe** abuse legacy champion from *Weapons of Legacy* or uncanny trickster from *Complete Scoundrel*. These classes progress any one other class at some of their levels—which means that, unlike typical spell-progressing prestige classes, you could choose ultimate magus for them. The argument is basically that nothing says you can’t pick something you have finished, and the wording on them has it improves your level so level-scaling things are improved. The typical usage is hellfire warlock from *Fiendish Codex II*. The entire thing is on incredibly thin ice, as far as the rules go, and I wouldn’t expect many DMs to actually go for it.

Note that neither class offers progression at 1st, that uncanny trickster is only three levels long, and that legacy champion is rather painful to enter thanks to the terrible rules for legacy weapons, so even if this is allowed, you’re missing out on another level of your “primary” class, which is brutal, and either getting just two levels of your secondary class out of it or else have to deal with the awfulness of *Weapons of Legacy*.

Really, I don’t recommend it. Just accept that you traded one level of your primary spellcasting for eight levels of your secondary spellcasting and some useful class features (you *did* make sure to [advance your primary class at every ultimate magus level](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105746/4563), right?), and after 15th focus on the primary spellcasting with whatever other prestige class catches your fancy.

If that’s really not acceptable to you—and, to be fair, it is, perhaps absurdly, not an equitable trade, you do give up more than you get—then you are better off just saying that to the DM and asking for some kind of houserule extending ultimate magus or something. After all, you would definitely have to ask your DM about how legacy champion or uncanny trickster interact with “finished” prestige classes anyway, so while you’re there you might as well ask for what you actually want.

The **other** alternative, in a high-level game, is to use ultimate magus to progress some other prestige class that gets its own spellcasting—sublime chord from *Complete Arcane* or Nar demonbinder from *Unapproachable East* are the typical choices. Sublime chord is only ten levels long, so getting eight levels of progression gets you almost everything (and uncanny trickster could get you the other two, if desired), and Nar demonbinder is only seven so you finish it before you even finish ultimate magus. Note that neither sublime chord nor Nar demonbinder is Intelligence-based, so that is a downside (I’m fairly sure there is no strong Intelligence-based choice here—assassin is an *interesting* idea, but not a very good one). Sublime chord is also going to be **very** difficult to enter without losing more levels off your primary progression; I’m not 100% sure it’s even possible.

1. <sub>Eldritch theurge from *Complete Mage* and noctumancer from *Tome of Magic* are both sort of arcane/arcane, but neither helps you—along with arcane spellcasting, the former progresses eldritch invocations and the latter shadow magic mysteries. These things are described as “arcane” but neither can continue to progress the same classes that ultimate magus progressed.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

While not specifically an Arcane/Arcane PrC solution, if You use **Sha'ir (Dragon Compendium)** as 1 of Your 2 Arcane Classes, You can keep dual-progressing using Mystic Theurge, Arcane Hierophant, Fochlucan Lyrist and other Arcane/Divine dual-progression PrC's. This is because Sha'ir is considered to be both a Divine and Arcane caster.

As pointed out in the comment, Sha'ir is neither spellbook-based nor spontaneous spellcaster, but this can be easily solved using **feats**, for example **Alacritous Cogitation**, which gives one spontaneous spell slot to Sha'ir.

Comment: Ultimate magus requires that one of your classes be able to “prepare […] from a spellbook,” and the other be “spontaneous.” Neither really describes sha’ir. The word “spontaneous” is under-defined in the rules, so maybe the sha’ir’s weird system would be considered spontaneous by some, but I wouldn’t and I suspect a lot of other DMs wouldn’t either. You should at least mention that issue. There may also be shenanigans to get a sha’ir to use a spellbook for some things (the way a cleric might for *anyspell* or a paladin would for Sword of the Arcane Order), which would be good additions here.

Comment: Thanks, added relevant information. I wouldn't even call it shenanigans really, D&D 3.5 is designed to use such workarounds for PRC requirements all the time, due to beyond-nonsensical requirements themselves, on pretty much everything.

Comment: I very much doubt that the authors considered the requirements they wrote to be “beyond-nonsensical,” or that the abilities they wrote were intended to be workarounds for them. Nonetheless, Alacritous Cogitation is a good call.